# Tensorflow load images with "value" from Dataframe

Tags: pandas, tensorflow

I want to load images with its corresponding value from a Pandas DataFrame into a Tensorflow Dataset. So the image path in `df['image_path']` should be my `X` feature and the value in `df['followers_like_ratio']` should be the target `y` value that I want to eventually predict.

So how can I load this into Tensorflow?

My data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that image_path is he FULL path to the image.  Also assume wntries in followers_like_path are STRINGS which represent the class labels. You can use ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_datafame to create a generator to load the data into model.fit. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
target_size=(224,224) # set the size of the images
color_mode='rgb' # set the type of image
class_mode= 'categorical' # set the class mode
batch_size=32  # set the batch size
val_split=.2 # set % of images to use for validation
subset='training' # set to 'training', or 'valiatiom' or leave as None
train_gen=ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=val_split).flow_from_datafram(df, 
          x_col='image_path',
          y_col='followers_like_ratio',target_size=target_size,color_mode=color_mode,
          class_mode=class_mode, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True, seed=123,
          subset='training')
valid_gen= ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=val_split).flow_from_datafram(df, 
          x_col='image_path',
          y_col='followers_like_ratio',target_size=target_size,color_mode=color_mode,
          class_mode=class_mode, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True, seed=123,
          subset='validation')
```

If you have a test_df you can create a test generator. You can use the sklearn train_test_split to seperate your original data frame ino a train_df and test_df as follows

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_size=.8 # set the % to use for training
train_df, test_df=train_test_split(df, train_size=train_size, shuffle=True, randoom_state=123)
```

NOW use train_df in the validation and train generators and test_df in the test generator

```
test_gen=ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_datafram(test_df,  x_col='image_path',
          y_col='followers_like_ratio',target_size=target_size,color_mode=color_mode,
          class_mode=class_mode, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
y_true=test_gen.labels
```

Comment: I thought that using categorical isn't the right way to solve a regression problem?